# There is group a $S$ with $2n$ members $n$ of them are identical and $n$ of them are different, How many subsets are there?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I have the following question :

There is a set $S$ with $2n$ members $n$ of them are identical and $n$ of them are different, How many different subsets are there for $S$ in size $n$.

**This is what I did:**

Lets choose $k$ members from the $n$ member that are identical and $r$ members from the different members so that $k+r=n$

Since there are $n$ identical members for $k>0 \implies k=1$ since $\{x,x,x..,x\}=\{x\}$

So we get the following :

$$k+r=n$$
Case $k=0$
$$0+n=n$$ 
Case $k>0$
$$1+n-1=n$$
Since there $n$ different members for the last equation we need to choose ${n \choose n-1}=n$

Therefore we get the number of subsets are $n+1$ which is wrong the answer should be $2^n$

Any ideas why my answer is incorrect? and why the answer is $2^n$?
Thank you.

Comment: What does it mean for members to be identical or different? Are the "identical" members different from the "different" members"? Are the "different" members different from other "different" members? You need to phrase the problem more clearly.

Comment: "identical" is very misleading here. I guess that the problem is actually something like: there are $n$ white balls and $n$ balls having distinct non-white colors, ...

Comment: If you want a subset with $n$ elements, the two ways are to have $n-1$ elements from the distinct set and add one from the identical set or have all the $n$ elements distinct.

Comment: @joriki These are good questions, yet the book don't refer to these issues, anyhow I assume that identical members are not different members, like $chi$ explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to answer "how many collections have $n$ elements", then the answer is $2^n$. We can choose $k$ of the distinct elements and $n-k$ of the identical elements. Thus we have 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n
\end{align*}

Comment: This is the answer in the book, yet I don't understand how do you choose $n-k$ identical elements if they are identical could you please expand you answer?

Comment: What we are forming are groups of objects - not sub sets. Hence the group $\{x,x,x,1,2,3\}$ is different from the group $\{x, 1, 2, 3\}$.First group has 6 elements and the second group has 4 elements. It is like how many ways we can choose $n$ balls from $n$ identical blackballs and $n$ different colored balls (none of which is black).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it is hard to tell what you are looking for. First of all, what do you mean by "identical"?

If I had to guess, I would say that you are looking for the [Power Set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $S'$, where $S'$ is a set with $ n $ (distinct) elements.

You can also prove that: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}= 2^n$ by inductive hypothesis